# How do I preserve a COM connection across webpages? (Electron)

Tags: javascript, html, arduino, serial-port, electron

I'm currently creating an electron application, where the main page is a list of actions a USB-connected device can do (arduino) and the command is sent via COM port (UART?). In the same application, I've a menu option that opens a new window where I can choose 4 com ports for 4 modules. How do I preserve the COM connection after the select com port window is closed? I suppose an alternative question could be- what is the right way to do this?

My rudimentary code is currently:

```
    // Connect to COM ports. Called from the COM port window
    connectCOM() {
        var sp = require("serialport");
        // Make all ports available

        var ports = new Array(4);
        var modport_text = [];
        var modport_value = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            /* Read options to find the selected COM ports to connect */
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < modport_value.length; i++) {
            if (modport_value[i] != "0") {
                ports[i] = new sp(modport_text[i], {
                    baudRate: 9600,
                    parser: new sp.parsers.Readline("\r\n")
                });
            } else {
                ports[i] = -1;
            }
        }

        localStorage.setItem("allports", JSON.stringify(ports));
        this.logPorts();
}
// Other functions

    // For debugging purposes. This displays the connections over console.
    // Called from Main window
    logPorts() {
        var sp = require("serialport");
        //var ports: typeof sp;
        var ports = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allports"));

        ports[0].on("open", () => {
            console.log("this will never output");
        });
    }
```

Is this even the right way to proceed?
Serializing the object does not preserve the `Serialport` properties, and I don't even know if it'll keep the serial port open.